# how to disable tooltip in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tooltip, disable

I want to make the tooltip visible only when I first install and run the app and then disable it.
Fortunately, the tooltip is visible only when the app is first run, and the tooltip is not visible from the beginning when the app is run later. The problem is that the tooltip appears again when the user clicks where the widget is located. . I want to make the tooltip completely inactive so that the tooltip doesn't fire even when the user touches the widget, but I don't know how.

```
  late Future<bool> _checkNew; 
  SuperTooltipController _tooltipController = SuperTooltipController();
  bool _tooltipVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   _checkNew = isFirstTime();
    _showGuideTooltip();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        _showTooltipVisible();
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            if (_tooltipVisible)
              SuperTooltip(
                popupDirection: TooltipDirection.down,
                borderColor: Colors.black,
                borderWidth: 1.0,
                controller: _tooltipController,
                content: const Text(
                  "i want know how to disable tooltip",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ...another widgets
             ],
            ),
          ),
        );
       }



  Future<bool> isFirstTime() async {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLaunch = sharedPreferences.getBool('_checkNew') ?? true;

    if (isFirstLaunch) {
      await sharedPreferences.setBool('_checkNew', false);
    }
    return isFirstLaunch;
  }

  void _showGuideTooltip() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      bool isFirstTimeUser = await _checkNew;
      if (isFirstTimeUser) {
        _tooltipController.showTooltip();
        setState(() {
          _tooltipVisible = true;
        });
      } else {

      }
    });
  }

  void _showTooltipVisible() {
    setState(() {
      _tooltipVisible = !_tooltipVisible;
    });
    if (_tooltipVisible) {
      _tooltipController.showTooltip();
    } else {
      _tooltipController.hideTooltip();
    }
  }
```

this is my code. plz find the problems. thank u

Comment: you forget to update  `_checkNew` to be `true` after user open the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is the problem with the package because even after removing "GestureDetector" wiget the tap is getting detected. There is no way we can enable or disable the tooltip,

**Likely solution:** Use "showcaseview" package which is popular & good for Highlighting widgets step by step.
link : https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview